# Ajax doesnt send data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Im trying to create my register page that posting the data to PHP File using Ajax and then the PHP file Check the Error of the form and return some error

My Form

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/extra/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var fname=$('#firstname').val();
var lname=$('#lastname').val();
var displayname=$('#displayname').val();
var password=$('#password').val();
var cpassword=$('#cpassword').val();
var email=$('#email').val();
var terms=$('#terms').val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "register.php",
data: "firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname+"&displayname="+displayname+"&password="+password+"&cpassword="+cpassword+"&email="+email+"&term="+terms ,
success: function(html){
$("#load").css('display','block');
$("#signupform").css('display','none');
$("#box").css('display','none');
$("#loading").fadeOut('500', function(){
$("#loading").css('display','none');
$("#box").html(html).show('slow');
});
}
});
return false;

});
});
</script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
#loading
{
display:none;
width:500px;
height:500px;
background:url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>

 <div id="loading" style="">
</div>
<div id="box">
</div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Fistname</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control inp" placeholder="Fistname" minlength="3" maxlength="50" value="" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Lastname</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control inp" placeholder="Lastname" minlength="3" maxlength="50" value="" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Displayname</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" name="displayname" id="displayname" class="form-control inp" placeholder="Displayname" minlength="3" maxlength="50" value="" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control inp" value="" placeholder="Email" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control inp" value="" placeholder="Password" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control inp" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="yes" checked> Accept<a href="#" target="_blank"> Term</a></label><div id="err_terms" class="err"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Button --> 
                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info signup-bt" id="submit" name="submit"> &nbsp <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>  Register</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

And Here it's My PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['fistname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['displayname'])) {
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$cpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cpassword']);
$displayname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['displayname']);
$checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE email='$email'");
$checkname = mysql_query("SELECT `displayname` FROM `users` WHERE displayname='$displayname'");
if(mysql_num_rows($checkemail) != 0){
  echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>';
}
if(mysql_num_rows($checkname) != 0){
echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>'; 
}
if($terms!="yes"){
 echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>'; 
}
if($password!=$cpassword){
  echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>';
}
if($displayname==""){
echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>'; 
}
if($password==""){
echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>';
}
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>';
}
if($terms != "yes"){ 
echo '<span class="message error">Something</span>';
}
else{
// QUERY
}
}
```

When I click Submit, And I try to check HTTP Header, It's doesnt send data to register.php
So.. How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: What about having some clear code not looking hat messy? Fisrt try to detect the error yourself.

Comment: Look into your dev's console in your browser. Get the output in the Networks tab and just try to solve the problem yourself first.
As you stated out, check your JS. There must be an error in your JS first!

Comment: You appear to be missing an opening form tag.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: your form should have an `id="submit"`, not the send button. Wrap your html inside a `<form id="submit">`...`</form>`, remove the id from the submit button, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is, for lack of better description, "confused" change your button type from `submit` to `button` so it wont' try to submit:

```
<button id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-info signup-bt" id="submit" name="submit"> &nbsp <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>  Register</button>
```

You should be passing an object and not a string for post ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "register.php",
   data: { 
      "firstname": fname,
      "lastname": lname,
      "displayname": displayname,
      "password": password,
      "cpassword": cpassword,
      "email": email,
      "term": terms
   },
   success: function(html){ /* you success function here*/
});
```

Comment: it's still doesnt send data to register.php

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
if(isset($_POST['fistname']) && ...
```

Should be 'firstname'.